# Is it true that $Z^TZ=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra

There's some matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, and $1 \leq m < n$, and rank $A=m$.

The $\mathrm{Dim}(\mathrm{Null}(A)) = n-m$

I have defined matrix $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times (n-m)}$ in which the columns form a base of $\mathrm{Null}(A)$.

Is it true to affirm that $Z^TZ = I$ ? I'm trying to find a way to verify if that's true.

Comment: You need the basis for the null space to be orthogonal for this to be true. The basis must be linearly independent, which implies that $Z^TZ$ has full rank, but $Z^TZ=I$ is a stronger condition.

Comment: @whpowell96 can I suppose that this orthogonal basis always exists?

Comment: Any linearly independent basis can be made orthogonal using the Gram-Schmidt procedure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process among other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider a simple example.

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Here $m=2,n=3$, and the rank is $2$. The $\mathrm{Dim}(\mathrm{Null}(A))=1$. The nullspace of $A$ is generated by
$$Z=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ -2\\ -1\end{pmatrix}$$.

Now, $$Z^T Z= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ -2\\ -1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 6 \end{pmatrix} \neq I$$